# Python 3.x field widths and lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint

List = [randint(0,99) for i in range(20)]
print("%3s" % List)
List.sort()
print("%3s" % List)
```

so i've been working on this code to give me a random list of 20 inputs between 0 and 99. Did i do the print statements correctly so that it would print 20 per line with a field with of 3?

Comment: Looks correct, you can always try running the code.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question or run the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your work by installing python from there web service if you have not already. Then you will be able to compile and run the files regarding to what Ramchandra said.